# Android error array out of boundaries

Tags: java, android, arrays, debugging, textview

I'm having a trouble with a simple program I made which was making a Textview field change whenether I used a button. I tried to find why everytime I try to run the app it always gets these error. Now I don't know why it is calling an error of array since I'm not using an array inside the code so it's confusing for me:

```
 package com.example.chu.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final TextView mTextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
       final Button pbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


        pbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mTextview.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.string1));

            }
        });
```

And the error that I'm getting is these:

```
  Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5
                                                                             at com.example.chu.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)



Process: com.example.chu.myapplication, PID: 5471
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chu.myapplication/com.example.chu.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5
```

Comment: You need to post what is at line 24

Comment: Try Clean Project and then rebuild.  If does not work, tr closing Android Studio and re-opening it. From the given code, I cannot see any array in your Source.

Comment: Line 24 is actually @Override above the public void onClick method.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but take a look at the length of the name of your button or the other components of yout program maybe a value is longer than the default value and causes that problem.